# Best node.js + postgresql web backend frame work for RESTful api?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, frameworks

I'm trying to build an app for `web`/`android`/`iOS`.
I'm thinking building a RESTful API backend using `Node.js` and `PostgreSQL` on a `AWS AMI EC2` server.
However, I'm not really used to developing with Node.js. Hence, the questions:

1) What is a nice backend framework to build RESTful API with Node.js and PostgreSQL?
2) What is the best frontend framework for (1)?

I've searched for (1) and many said `Express` but the last one was answered in 2015. For (2), it seems people are divided: `Angular`, `React`, and `Vue`.

Help please.

Comment: There are no 'best' frameworks, that's why such questions are off-topic. (1) Restify, Express (Sails, Feathers and Nestjs are derived frameworks), Fastify or whatever works for you (2) Any of the listed. You cannot estimate pros and cons without getting your hands dirty

Comment: @estus "getting your hands dirty" Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Backend use Express is the best option or you can use restify ,

and for Frontend use combination of EJS + VueJS

EJS (use for page rendering )

VueJS : create vue app in every page , use features for vue js (VueJS is  2nd highest starred on Github )

https://github.com/collections/front-end-javascript-frameworks

Comment: Never heard of EJS. I'll look into it, thanks!